# How to abstract a binary search that is not over a data structure?

Tags: java, search, numerical-methods, abstraction

I have a Java program in which I find that I've hand-implemented the binary search algorithm 3 separate times. The problem is that this search is not done over a filled-out data structure; rather, it is by calls to a numerical method that is computationally expensive (hence the binary search; I'm trying to reduce the number of calls to this method). The method header(s) looks like:

```
double computeValue1 (Thing thing, int parameter, int seed)
```

This method always returns a double between 0 and 1. The function is monotonic increasing (higher values of the `seed` always return higher output; and thus the binary search is justified). I'm using the search to find the value of `seed` that returns a value closest to 0.5 (given fixed `Thing` and `parameter`).

So ideally there would be some abstracted library method in Java that I could use to get this search accomplished, instead of having the details written out in my code. Moreover, I actually have this 3 different times for 3 different evaluation methods (say, `computeValue1`, `computeValue2`, and then a 3rd time where I'm doing the same search on `parameter` while keeping `Thing` and `seed` fixed).

What would be an elegant way to abstract out the binary search, so that I'm not maintaining 3 separate searching methods (one around each of the 3 computation methods) that are all mostly doing the same thing?

Comment: Could you include some more code?

Comment: If you're using Java 8, maybe you could do something like this: `double <T> computeValue(T thing, int parameter, int seed, Function<Thing, Double> expensiveFunction)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the data type for the search parameter is the same (`int` in your case), you can do this:

```
public int binarySearch(double targetValue, int from, int to, Function<Integer, Integer> compute) {
    while (...) {
        int currentParameter = ...;
        int currentValue = compute.apply(currentParameter);
        ...
    }
}
```

Call it like this in Java 8:

```
int seed1 = binarySearch(0.42, 0, 1000, s -> computeValue1(someThing, someParameter, s));
int seed2 = binarySearch(0.42, 0, 1000, s -> computeValue2(someThing, someParameter, s));
int param = binarySearch(0.42, 0, 1000, p -> computeValue1(someThing, p, someSeed));
```

If you don't have Java 8, you need to define the `Function` interface yourself:

```
public interface Function<TParameter, TResult> {
    TResult apply(TParameter parameter);
}
```

and invoke the search with an anonymous inner class:

```
int seed1 = binarySearch(0.42, 0, 1000, new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(Integer parameter) {
        return computeValue1(someThing, someParameter, parameter));
    }
});
```

Comment: That's nifty, I didn't know that in Java 8 you can now pass methods as parameters. Thanks for that news! (Also, the self-declared Function class was more elegant than I was coming up with, good stuff.)

Comment: Thanks! (The Java 8 one is even better, though, as it employs covariance and contravariance, giving more flexibility to the signature of the method parameter.) Note, though, that in this example, I'm not passing a method, I'm passing a [lambda expression](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html), which (together with streams) is the most awesome (and long overdue) feature of Java 8. You can pass methods too, though: `binarySearch(0.42, 0, 1000, this::myMethod)`, but then that method's signature must match the `Function` parameter type.

Comment: Just learning about lambda expressions in Java for the first time, and I wish I could give this about a hundred upvotes. So sweet!